# How to get the day of month from a formatted string?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime

When I create a `Date` from parsing a `String` and access the day of the month, I get the wrong value.

```
Date datearr = null;
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dataa = "17-03-2012";
try {
    datearr = df1.parse(dataa);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "err", 1000).show();
}

int DPDMonth = datearr.getMonth() + 1;
int DPDDay = datearr.getDay();
int DPDYear = datearr.getYear() + 1900;

System.out.println(Integer.toString(DPDDay)+"-"+Integer.toString(DPDMonth)+"-"+Integer.toString(DPDYear));
```

Why do I get `0` instead of `17`?

```
03-11 10:24:44.286: I/System.out(2978): 0-3-2012
```

Comment: Read the javadoc of the methods you use, notice their deprecation warning, and replace by the code that the documentation suggests. And also, think about what would happen if you had a ParseException, when the code `datearr.getMonth()` is executed.

Comment: And please use the java conventions related to variable naming... it is highly annoying trying to read code and have a variable highlighted as a class.

Comment: Sorry, its my first post in here.

Comment: You'll get more value out of SO if you do [a little research]() on your question and include what you've found. That way we know what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I hope my next post will be more serious. I inattentive at this time , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet the doesn't use deprecated methods anymore, fixes naming issues and simplifies the output.

```
    Date datearr = null;
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dataa = "17-03-2012";
    try {
        datearr = df1.parse(dataa);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "err", 1000).show();
        return;  // do not continue in case of a parse problem!!
    }

    // "convert" the Date instance to a Calendar
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(datearr);

    // use the Calendar the get the fields
    int dPDMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int dPDDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int dPDYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    // simplified output - no need to create strings
    System.out.println(dPDDay+"-"+dPDMonth+"-"+dPDYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
int DPDDay = datearr.getDate();
```

getDay() return a day in week

Answer (score 0):

This kind of work is much easier when using the third-party library, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

String dateString = "17-03-2012";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime( dateString ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();

int dayOfMonth = dateTime.getDayOfMonth();
```